# How is this question on holding a key for several seconds too broad?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

[Ruby, check if Input.press? key is held for several seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555309)

Yes, it's short and has no code, but the question is very clear to me. "I want to check if the user is holding a key for several seconds" - that's easy to follow.

Comment: From the question alone, it is totally unclear whether op writes a console application or uses some kind of GUI. There is probably no platform independent way to get key release events in consoles, so an answer would have to cover all possibilities. If op defines which os, and which app type, then it might be on-topic.

Comment: I disagree it's "totally unclear". If someone asks about detecing a key press without mentioning any framework, it's a fair assumption they are asking about the console and in as platform-agnostic way as possible.

Comment: Why should we have to make assumptions when the OP could simply tell us? Closing it urges them to do exactly that.

Comment: Every question has infinite implicit assumptions which OP could make explicit. I guess I will have to agree to disagree with the mods about which assumptions need to be made explicit.

Comment: @mahemoff Sure, I'm happy to agree to disagree. But it should also be clarified that no mods were involved in the closing of that question. It was closed by community voting and it's not a case *"mods vs us"*.

Comment: I'm referring to mods loosely as those users with sufficient privileges to close, but fair enough

Comment: Putting it on hold was intended to stop you from adding that answer.  You can ask the question yourself, no major reason to alter it from the original by the sound of it.   But beware you have a major credibility problem, nobody will believe you pulled it off.  So be sure to have to answer ready to quickly copy/paste it in the answer box after you submitted the question.

Comment: @ivarni All users on Stack Overflow are moderators.

Comment: As far as I can tell without any Ruby specific expertise, it looks to me like it has all the makings of an on-topic how-to question. Unfortunately these usually get a knee-jerk closure due solely to the length of the question and the fact that it is not a useless debugging question that will never ever help anyone else ever. That said, all of the users involved have at least a bronze badge in the tag (1 gold, 1 silver, and 3 bronze), so I'll have to defer to them. Unfortunately only one of them left a comment, and it was a possible duplicate comment that was contested.

Answer (score 4):

I am not the developer in Ruby, but the post mentioned in the link lacks detail on which platform, framework, environment or version the user is working on. There is also little information about the attempt the user made.

Actually, most of the time most of the experienced users understand what the user was asking for, but it is not the same case for everyone. That is why an MCVE is applied when asking a question.

Because if not, every new or amateur user will ask trivial or detail-less questions without try themselves first.

Quoting from *https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example*:

> When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if
>   you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce
>   the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example
>   (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a
>   minimal, workable example (mwe).
>
> Your code examples should be…
>
> …Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same
>   problem
>
> …Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce
>   your problem in the question itself
>
> …Reproducible – Test the code
>   you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

Comment: MCVE is only necessary for debugging questions. The question here is not about debugging. It lacks details, but it doesn't need a MCVE.

Comment: Why should it mention any platform or framework? It's a general question on Ruby programming, which one would reasonably expect to apply to any OS and the answer could use core Ruby or any applicable framework.

Comment: Attempts are not at all required for how-to questions. The inclusion of a failed attempt turns a how-to question into a debugging question. Contrary to popular belief, how-to questions are not and have never been inherently off-topic. They may be too broad, unclear, or otherwise off-topic, but those are problems that any question on Stack Overflow may face, not just how-to questions.

Comment: As well, the inclusion of irrelevant details to artificially limit the scope of a question is rarely ever a good thing. Especially if the solution is the same regardless of those irrelevant details.